# Mysql Date Field Search using months to find upcoming birthday

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, logic

I am trying to fins 'upcoming birthdays' of the users present in the Database.

I can able to fine the users upcoming birthday only till 12 month (Dec).

What if I need to find the upcoming birthday of next year.

My Query:

```
SELECT c.F_CONTACT_ID,
       c.F_CONTACT_NAME,
       c.F_CONTACT_FNAME,
       DATE_FORMAT(c.F_DOB, '%d/%m') F_DOB
FROM t_contact c
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(F_DOB, '%m') >= '08'
GROUP BY c.F_CONTACT_ID
ORDER BY c.F_DOB ASC LIMIT 0 ,
                           10
```

How can I find the upcoming birthday of the users who born on 'January' because the

> DATE_FORMAT(F_DOB, '%m') >= '08'

can able to check till 12th month.

Can some one help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why you have a `group by`.  I would do this with an `order by` and `limit`:

```
SELECT c.F_CONTACT_ID,
       c.F_CONTACT_NAME,
       c.F_CONTACT_FNAME,
       DATE_FORMAT(c.F_DOB, '%d/%m') F_DOB
FROM t_contact c
ORDER BY (case when month(c.F_DOB) >= '08' then month(c.F_DOB)
               else month(c.F_DOB) + 12
          end)
LIMIT 0, 10;
```

That is, add "12" to the month numbers for next year.  Note:  this doesn't take the day of the month into account because your original query does not.

Comment: How can I take date in this? i.e. Order should be in date then month. @Gordon